# Mystery process crashing machine by using all of the RAM - how to identify?

Tags: linux, memory-usage

I have a Linux machine which runs ~10 in house written processes.

Every other day(!) the machine completely runs out of RAM, goes into swap and becomes unresponsive. This happens quickly over a period of a couple of seconds, so it's not feasible to sit watching the machine until it dies. It's a sudden leak, not a gradual one, so top(1) doesn't give any indications something bad may about to happen.

What is the best way of identifying which process(es) are causing the trouble?

Comment: give us a hint about these processes: what are they doing, is it interpreted or native code? What are the developers saying?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look into disabling memory overcommit so the kernel would just kill the leaking process instead of the machine.

You can disable overcommit by using the following two sysctl:

```
vm.overcommit_ratio=60
vm.overcommit_memory=2
```

The first number depends on how much memory and how much swap you have. 
The allocation limit is going to be:

```
amount_of_swap + overcommit_ratio/100 * amount_of_ram
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set memory limits for each process with [bash ulimit](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-ulimit-147) command to prevent them from eating all system memory. To get notification I recommend using [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) to monitor each process memory usage.